# Convert active to passive voice sentence using Spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy

Want to convert active to passive voice using spacy in nlp. Can anyone help me?

I change subject to object and object to subject but i cant change verb as i need.

example:

They make cars in Detroit
Cars are made in Detroit

Mary cleans this room everyday
The room is cleaned everyday by Mary

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp("They make cars in Detroit")
s = list(doc)
tmp,temp,sub = "","",-1
for i in doc:
    if i.pos_ == 'VERB':
        s[i.i] = i
    elif i.dep_ == 'nsubj':
        sub = i.i
        temp = i
    elif i.dep_ == 'dobj':
        tmp = i.text.capitalize()
        s[i.i] = temp
        s.insert(i.i,"by")

s[sub] = tmp
print(' '.join(str(e) for e in s))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to modify the verb forms, you need a morphological analyzer (`makes` in base form -> `make`) and a morphological generator (base form `make` as past participle -> `made`, as present participle -> `making`). Spacy can do the analysis step for English, but not the generation step, so you'll need to look for additional tools.